# Maintain Back Stack in Android Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a list view in Android. During every click of list item, I have load a Single view name "Template Fragment" for every click dynamically. After click on Sub Views, I have loaded the same View "Template Fragment" again dynamically. Now I have multiple views creating from the same Fragment. 
Now my problem is to maintain back stack of all the views. How I can achive this.

Please help me for the same.

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add the fragments to the backstack with different tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the following code,

```
//add to back stack
transaction.addToBackStack(type.getClass().getName());

//Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

String as parameter might help in identifying fragments

In case you don't need to identify this back stack later on, pass **null** for `addToBackStack`.

Comment: Currently What I put on the parameter of addToBackStack, if i am on fifth view.

Comment: do you want to maintain state of all fragments loaded ??

Comment: if so then try giving unique string each time you start a fragment, i guess that might help in maintaining its state